# How to display number of rows in SQL Table to an HTML container

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm making a Bug Tracker application using ASP.Net using MVC. Whenever a ticket gets created, it gets added to my Tickets.sql database. On my VIEW dashboard.cshtml of my application, I want to be able to display the number of tickets there is inside of the Ticket Database. But I'm getting stuck trying to implement the function. I'm not sure how to do it either. I'd appreciate some help with the process and with knowing what I need to do.

My Dashboard that shows where the number of tickets should be displayed:

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3>Unresolved Tickets</h3>
                </div>
                <div id="num-unresolved-tickets" class="panel-body">
                    <h2 class="text-center">
                        <?php>
                            $SELECT COUNT(ID) AS UserId FROM Tickets;
                        </?php>
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3>Resolved Tickets</h3>
                </div>
                <div id="num-resolved-tickets" class="panel-body">
                    <h2 class="text-center">4</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you tell us where you are stuck? you need to share the code which is trying to display the count. Without seeing your code we don't know what's the issue and how it can be solved.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I'm sorry I'm kinda new to Stackoverflow. I just posted a snippet of the code I'm working on. I think it involves some sort of PHP or Node.Js to connect to my database. But I thought Visual Studios would do the job for me and fetch the information for me if I used some PHP.  

Like I said, I'm not very familiar with this type of stuff.

Comment: @ChristianMartinez, Please check my answer if works for you. If your question has been solved , you can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research, it is hard for us to achieve data from database in the `cshtml` directly.

We can use `c#` code to execute `SqlCommand` to show data in the `cshtml`.

First, we need to add the following class to deal with `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

```
public class SqlHelper
    {

        private SqlConnection con;
        //To Handle connection related activities    
        private void connection()
        {
            string constr = "CONNSTR";
            con = new SqlConnection(constr);

        }

        public string ExecuteSql(string sql)
        {
            connection();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql,con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
  
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                return reader.GetName(0)+ ": "+reader[0].ToString();
               
            }
            con.Close();
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Second, we can call the method in the controller.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS UserId FROM Tickets";
            SqlHelper helper = new SqlHelper();
            ViewBag.Message = helper.ExecuteSql(sql);
            return View();
        }
```

Third, please set the following cshtml.

```
<h2>Index</h2>
<div id="num-unresolved-tickets" class="panel-body">
    <h2 class="text-center">
        <b style="color:red"> @ViewBag.Message</b>
    </h2>
</div>
```

Finally, you can get the correct result.

[image]